# Why live to ground voltage is only 0V (in a 220V AC power outlet & there is also electric shock on the panel)?

Tags: electrical-panel, grounding, electric-motor, voltage, power-supply

my name is Kelvin. I'm a trainee hydraulic engineer in Indonesia. I apologize if this question has been answered before / if this question is too basic. So we have a problem with electric shock coming from an electric panel. This panel runs on 220V AC supply & is used to run an inverter (single phase input & three phase output) to run a three phase electric motor. We checked the supply voltage from live to neutral, live to ground & neutral to ground. The result is shown below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

then we checked the electric outlet where the power for the panel is coming from. We measured the voltage again, but the result for 'live to ground' voltage is different
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the voltage from live to ground at the power outlet is only 0V, but the one in the electric panel is 133V
Are there any possible reasons for this to be happening? Might this the reason an electric shock is happening on the panel?
Here is the simple electrical diagram for the panel.
[image]
Thank you in advance for your help, any sorts of comments are appreciated :)

Comment: what inverter type/model is it ?

Comment: You lost the ground

Comment: @Ruskes the brand is Kinco, model number CV20-2S-0015G

Comment: Where do you get an electric shock? By touching the outside of the panel?

Comment: You should install an RCD, to prevent such errors to cause any harm to you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about a commercial installation and, therefore is _not_ [diy.se].

Comment: Since you are generating the AC power locally, **grounding and bonding do not exist unless YOU create it**.   From the measurements it appears neutral is not bonded to ground, and I'm betting you don't have physical ground spikes/rods either to tie the whole thing to *physical* earth.  Install it properly to local codes (if none, use Euro codes). Why are you seeing weird voltages between neutral and ground? "Phantom voltage" from use of a random high impedance DVM.  This is from "capacitive coupling" across nearby wires and lacks even the power to move the needle on an old analog voltmeter.

Answer (score 5):

0 volts on live to ground means the ground is broken somewhere, either a bad connection or a broken wire.

Start at the 0v point and work all the back to the panel till you find full volts again.

Fix the connection/broken wire and you should get full voltage again.